# c# input string formatting error

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to get data from my mysql databas. I'm able to get all the data from the db, but I'd like to format one of my columns in a currency format. However, I'm getting an input string error when I try.

My code:

```
var result = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Requests");
var data = result.Select(x => new 
{
    TimeStamp = Convert.ToString(x.TimeStamp),
    TelephoneNumber = x.TelephoneNumber,
    Make = x.Make,
    Model = x.Model,
    Body_Type = x.Body_Type,
    StockNum = x.StockNumber,
    Price = String.Format("{0:C}",  Int32.Parse(x.Price)),
    InventoryDate = x.Inventory_Date          
}).ToArray();
```

The "Price" line is causing my input string error

Comment: what is  the type of `x.Price`? what exactly is the error message in the exception? why are you carrying out a `String.Format`operation within a `String.Format` operation?

Comment: @user3434042 and what is the value when you step through the code? what is the exact error message?

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

which would suggests that what is entered my not be a string, but there are for sure no alphabetic characters.

Comment: are you absolutely certain there are no null values being passed in? or non numeric-characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
Price = String.Format("{0:C}", String.Format("{0:C}", Int32.Parse(x.Price)))
```

to:

```
Price = String.Format("{0:C}", Int32.Parse(x.Price))
```

And see if it works correctly?

Alternatively, try the following:

```
Price = Int32.Parse(x.Price).ToString("C")
```

Depending on the value of `x.Price`, it may also be better to cast it to a `float`, `double` or `decimal` as well, rather than an `Int32`.

Comment: that was an error when typing in the question. Unfortunately, that does not solve my problem.

Comment: @user3434042 what is the value of `x.Price`?

Comment: There are several values (strings) formatted as "54231"

Comment: @user3434042 I've added in another method for you to try

Comment: I get the same error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @user3434042 glad I could help.